# Abel sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the series 
$$1-2^2 + 3^2 - \dots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^2$$
What is the Abel sum of this series?

Comment: The zeta regularization of such divergent series is just zero, since $\eta(s)=(1-2/2^s)\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(-2)=0$.

Comment: If I have well understood the question, start from
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^{n+1}x^n=-\frac{1}{1+x}$$
valid for $|x|<1$, and apply two times the operator $x\frac{d}{dx}$.